# Data does not save from Django Admin

Tags: django, admin

I have developed two tables which is LineNumber and PhotoNumber. And both of the tables had relationship of manytomany. So I created another table LinePhoto. 
And I've register all the table in Admin. The problem is I can insert data for LineNumber and PhotoNumber through django admin and all the data were inserted in my database table. But when I insert data for LinePhoto. The data does not inserted in my databse table. For your information I'm using postgres.

Admin.py

```
class LineNumberadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = LineNumber 
    list_display_links = ('line_number','year_id')
    list_display = ('line_number','year_id')
    search_fields = ('line_number',)

class PhotoNumberadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = LineNumber 
    list_display_links = ('photo_number',)
    list_display = ('photo_number',)
    search_fields = ('photo_number',)

class LinePhotoadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = LinePhoto
    list_display_links = ('pn_id','ln_id')
    list_display = ('pn_id','ln_id')
    search_fields = ('pn_id__photo_number','ln_id__line_number',)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not surprising: django admin does not fill `LinePhotoadmin` automatically for you. A Django admin form only operate on its respective models that are properly defined.

Comment: What do you by models that are properly define?  After i check i found that not all the data that i set/insert through LinePhotoAdmin were inserted/save in my database table.

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/. In Django admin you can only create instances of models. What you are trying to do here is to establish relationship between objects. Django Admin is simply not capable of doing so.